# preg_match in php

Tags: php

How do I use preg_match in php to match a whole word on its own and not when it's part of another word.

ie.

151 : 151-220 - should be a match.
51 : 151-220 - should not be a match.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/\b151\b/', $string)
```

`\b` matches a "word boundary"

Comment: May or may not be relevant, but you should use `preg_quote($strActionKey, '/')` which escapes regular expression characters that might occur inside your ActionKey.

Comment: If that doesn't explain the problem, we'll need to know more detail. `preg_match('/\b151\b/', '151-220');` does match, while `preg_match('/\b51\b/', '151-220');` does not, so there must be more going on than you've given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\b` in your regular expressions. They are word boundaries. E.g: `/\b151\b/`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\b` modifier, which indicates word boundaries.

```
preg_match('/\b...\b/', $your_string);
```